# How to call another components method in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components

How to call the function of another component in angular 2.
I have two component and I want to call a method from the other component.

Actually, there is no parent-child relationship between those 2 components, as the overview component is a routed component, so I can't use @ViewChild

[I want to achieve this call project method from header section from all page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUCfy.png)

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672656/angular-call-function-from-other-component?

Comment: Yes! this working for me, now I am able to call method/service but page/view not updated.

Comment: please help me how to triggered the view if object value changed

Comment: Here is the component reference about types of interaction between angular components [component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to have [Angular Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) with method that can be accessed from anywhere in the world.

Otherwise, you can call methods from child component as mentioned [here.](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild)

Comment: Actually, I am using service from child class component. and I want to call child method from parents class components. and I tried to call from parents using @ViewChild but it gives error and not working for me

Comment: actually, there is no parent-child relationship between those 2 components, as the overview component is a routed component, so I can't use @ViewChild.