# Angular: call function from other component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make two angular components and I want to call a function from the first component in the second component. When I try this I get following error message: `Cannot red property 'functionName' of undefined`. How can this be solved?

Here a link of an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rre4gb

Comment: for a quick start, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the component you want to call its function, is not instantiated.

for component communication you can use a `service` instead:

### Service

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    myCustomFunction(){
    }
}
```

### Component

in your component:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-component',
   providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyComponent {

   // inject your service to make it available
   constructor(private service: MyService){}

   doStuff(){

      // call function which is located in your service
      this.service.myCustomFunction();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, I would prefer a shared service with a `Subject` among these components.

**service**:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService  {

  mySubject = new Subject();

}
```

**WorldComponent** (subscriber):

```
export class WorldComponent  {
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService){
    this.sharedService.mySubject.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.worldFunction();
    })
  }
```

**HelloComponent**(publisher):

```
public helloFunction() {
    alert('Hello');
    this.sharedService.mySubject.next(true);
  }
```

You can find the updated example here: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnvmkq?file=app%2Fworld.component.ts**

Answer (score 2):

The best way to share information between multiple components is generally through a service.

Create a separate file: file.service.ts

Provide the service in the app.module.ts file

Inject the service into each component. Then you'll have access to the variables in both components

See this: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 0):

the reason of the error is that the hello component is not imported, but instead of calling a component from another, you should use a service in between, as other answers already suggested.